# Serial port read difference between putty and pyserial

Tags: python, python-2.7, putty, pyserial

I am reading some data from the serial port when  I read the data from the putty the output is look like:

```
X7_SEM_V3_6
SC 01
FS 09
ICAP OK
RDBK OK
INIT OK
SC 02
O>
```

But when I write a code in a python using pyserial it didn't read the last line `O>`

```
X7_SEM_V3_6
SC 01
FS 09
ICAP OK
RDBK OK
INIT OK
SC 02
```

here is the code; please someone has any knowledge please share

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools
import fileinput
import serial, time
import binascii
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB3"
ser.baudrate = 38400
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE              
ser.xonxoff = False    
ser.rtscts = False    
ser.dsrdtr = False  
number_address = 1341602
number_char = 9  
timeout=1

count =0
f=open('lut100.txt','r')

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()


if ser.isOpen():


         ser.flushInput()
         ser.flushOutput()
# reading        
         max_packet = 20
         while True:

            byteData = ser.read_until('\r',max_packet)
            newdata=str(byteData)
            print newdata.strip() 
else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Comment: Is there perhaps no carriage return at the end of the last line?

Comment: Yes may be any solution?

Comment: The solution is don't use `read_until`.

Comment: Instead read_until  what should do to read first eight line to read until late O